# Networking - Routing data through a server

Tags: networking, wide-area-network

I have 3 devices, let's call them `A`, `B`, and `C`. The ping between `A` and `B` is 200ms, and between `A` and `C` is 30ms. However, the ping between `B` and `C` is 60ms. This is how routing works in this region, the network data `A` and `B` is jumping through a `D` point located far away which causes the increase in ping.

My question is... Is it possible to make the data from point `A` and `B` to route through `C`?

Comment: Please include a network diagram and be sure to include any router on it, and what you own and control.

Comment: It's possible if you have access to configure routing on those devices.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the data from point A and B to route through C?

Yes. You need to reconfigure the routes on both A and B to point to the gateway C instead of D. If the route towards D comes over a dynamic route that you can't/don't want to change you can set a static route with a lower metric.